# The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Future<QuerySnapshot> Firestore/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a little trouble with returning data into *_allResults* list. I do get an error data.docs as it shows that "The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Future'". Maybe someone have any clue what could be the reason for it?

Thank you in advance!

**Code snippet**

```
getItemStreamSnapshots() async {
var data = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Books')
    .get();
setState(() {
  _allResults = data.docs;
});
searchResultsList();
return "complete";
}
```

Comment: var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Books')
    .get(); just add await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [method `get`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html) you are calling is:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> get([GetOptions options])
```

It returns a Future, not a `QuerySnapshot`. You can `await` for the result since your method is `async`:

```
final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Books').get();
```